# can't recall data saved by PersistJS

Tags: jquery, persist

i'm having a jquery variable containing so much formatted data created by ckeditor and trying to pass it to another page without reloading so i'm using ajax but can't pass this variable as a query string because it has so much formatted data so i'm trying to use PersistJS to save this variable. no problem with saving it and calling it back at the same page but the problem occurred when i was testing it. i have 2 pages page1 with this code

```
var proDetails = $('textarea.editor').val();
var store = new Persist.Store('My Data Store');
var data = proDetails;
store.set('saved_data', data);
```

page2 containing this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
store.get('saved_data', function(ok, val) {
if (ok)
alert('saved data = ' + val);
}); 
});
```

but it doesn't work and for sure i'm calling the persist-min.js in both pages
and if it didn't work is there anyway to save the proDetails variable in a php session so i can call it in the other page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not initialized `store` object on page 2.

Comment: thanks i just applied the explanation from the man site thought it's going to access it just like cookies calling it directly thanks so much

Comment: just last question how can i access this variable with php to inert into db my main purpose is to to pass this variable into the php code

Comment: i know javascript is client side and php is server side but i'm on a project to add products and i want to add the product using ajax without refreshing the page and the js variable containing the much formatted data can't be sent using query string looking for another solution. now data is saved to the variable val by using PersistJS still looking for solutions

Comment: You can do it only through AJAX, it is not possible to assign a javascript value directly into php scriplets.

Comment: Check this page http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/php/20076-passing-javascript-variable-php.html

Answer (score 1):

You could send that long string of data through POST, which doesn't suffer the size limitation of a GET request.

Keep in mind that those data will not be sent to your server if you use PersistJS.
Other than that juzerali already replied to you

Comment: Ajax-ing data via POST is fairly common, even for small amounts of data, just expect it as a Stream on the server side rather than strings. So you will need to read the Stream into a string/byte[], I'm sure you can find lots of examples.